# Changing dryer plug from 4 prong to 3

Tags: electrical

I'm changing the plug on my dryer from 4 prong to 3 prong I've almost got it off but one of the screws holding the wire on when I turn it it just turns and turns and turns but doesn't move what do I do I really need to get I fixed so I can do laundry

Comment: I take it you're changing the dryer plug because you either got a used replacement dryer and need to change it over to a 3 prong cord to plug in, or because you moved to a new-to-you house that has a 3 prong outlet in it?  Either way, can you turn the breaker for the dryer off, then open up the dryer outlet box and post photos of the inside for us please?

Comment: Yes I can how do I post the pictures?

Comment: use magnet screwdriver to pull it out

Comment: Your question is not about changing the plug type but about a screw that wont come out

Comment: That's a bad idea. 3-prong is less safe. NEVER do this unless you have no other choice.

Comment: @AlishaJerkins -- hit the [edit] button under your post in "share edit ..." then use the button in the editor toolbar that looks like a mountain and sun to add them